# RxJS: Take every x seconds

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

with RXJs I am trying to achieve something like this:

1. `clickStream.bufferWithTime(500).subscribe(f)`
2. `clickStream.throttle(500).subscribe(f)`

Version 1 calls `f` every 500ms no matter if there was a clickEvent or not.
Version 2 calls `f` only if clickStream did send a clickEvent and then stopped for at least 500ms.

I would like to to call `f` every 500ms as long as `clickStream` is emitting events. As soon as it does stop to emit, `f` should called be one last time. If `clickStream` restarts to emit the same should happen again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
clickStream.bufferWithTime(500).filter(arr => arr.length > 0).subscribe(f)
```